# How should I upgrade my Java compiler

Tags: java, macos, compiler-construction

When I run `$ javac Simulator.java` then I get the following warning:

`warning: ./particle_simulator/Atom.class: major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.`

I don't know why I suddenly get this warning as I haven't made substantial changes to my code.  Nevertheless, how do I upgrade my Java compiler?

I'm running Mac OSX 10.7.5 and my Java version is below:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Go To the [Oracle Web site and download it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: About the Java Update for Mac OS X v10.3.9   http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1537 reference doc .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download the JDK from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ . Make sure you get the OSX version. It has its own installer so installation should be pretty straight forward.